# Timescale run_job() cannot find defined FUNCTION/PROCEDURE

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

i am creating a PROCEDURE in TimescaleDB (which is based on PostgreSQL) like this:

```
CREATE or replace procedure insert_oee()
LANGUAGE SQL
as $$
INSERT INTO public.oee_t1 (columns)
    (select
        some_columns
     from
     a_table)
$$;
```

Which works fine and does not return any error when creating.

and then I am creating a job like this:

```
SELECT add_job('job_name','24h',initial_start=> 'some_date')
```

which works fine too.

and then when trying to run it like this:

```
call run_job(1002)
```

i get the error '*function public.insert_oee(job_id INT, config JSONB) not found*'

but if I list all the procedures like this:

```
SELECT
*
FROM 
    information_schema.routines
WHERE 
    routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
```

the procedure is listed.

Why do I get the error?

Answer (score 2):

this [post](https://www.timescale.com/forum/t/schedule-backfill/290) can be helpful: there are some parameters to be specified as it is said in [this documentation page](https://docs-dev.timescale.com/docs-tutorial-candlestick/timescaledb/tutorial-candlestick/how-to-guides/user-defined-actions/create-and-register/#create).

You (that's funny) are missing the arguments when creating the procedure, run it again with this header and it will be fine; even if you pass nothing (which is equivalent to null,null) it will run fine.

```
CREATE or replace procedure insert_oee(job_id INT, config JSONB)
```

with the standard parameters specified.

Comment: Looks like you have a typo in that, you shouldn't nest the create or replace statements, but yes that's what you need to do!

Comment: @davidk thanks a lot, that was definitely a typo lol